# How to make threads going in and out critical section frequently?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am very new to `pthreads` so I have a question.
Assume there is a function like:

```
int a=20; //global variable
 void *decrement(void * tid)
{
   while(a>0)
   {
      printf("a= %d accessed by thread %d\n",a,tid);
      a=a-1; 
   }

}
```

and in the `main() function`, I create 6 threads:

```
for(i=0; i < 6; i++) {
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, decrement,(void*)i);
}
```

then the result will be:

```
a=20 accessed by theard 0
a=19 accessed by theard 0
a=18 accessed by theard 0
a=17 accessed by theard 0
a=16 accessed by theard 0
a=15 accessed by theard 0
a=14 accessed by theard 0
a=13 accessed by theard 0
a=12 accessed by theard 0
a=11 accessed by theard 0
a=10 accessed by theard 0
...
a=1 accessed by theard 0
a=20 accessed by theard 1
a=20 accessed by theard 2
```

but I want it like:

```
a=20 accessed by theard 0
a=19 accessed by theard 2
a=18 accessed by theard 0
a=17 accessed by theard 1
a=17 accessed by theard 3
a=15 accessed by theard 0
a=14 accessed by theard 2
a=14 accessed by theard 4
a=16 accessed by theard 5
a=15 accessed by theard 1
a=17 accessed by theard 6
...
a=1 accessed by theard 0
a=20 accessed by theard 1
a=20 accessed by theard 2
```

It means 6 threads going in and out the `decrement() function` many times.
How can I do that?
Or is there any way to go through the `increment function` with only 6 threads without using the while loop in it. 
PS: Dont care about concurrency because that what I want. :D
Thank in advance

Comment: If you're "very new to pthreads", I'd highly recommend learning to use it correctly before trying to deliberately use it incorrectly.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths thank you for your suggestion. Do I use it wrongly?

Comment: Based on what you posted as your desired output, it certainly looks like you're trying to use it wrongly. But you've used it wrongly, wrongly, because you haven't yet learned how to use it rightly. Hence the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You really can't because the threads are all trying to do the same thing -- print to standard output. So they'll just have to keep waiting for each other.

The way you want it is the worst possible result, since it will require a context switch for each line of output as one thread releases ownership of standard output and another thread acquires it. The most efficient result is for each thread to do as much work as possible before having to block while waiting to write.

If you really want to force the worst possible performance, you can put a call to `sched_yield` after the `printf`.

If you want concurrency, why are you creating a whole bunch of threads that do nothing but fight for the same resource?

Comment: Oh, what I want is a demo of concurrency. I thought If it is like the first result, it is not obvious since 6 threads only access simultaneously the first time when a=20. It would be great if it was like the second result. :D Another way is that I keep creating threads until a=0, but there are now more than 6 threads. Anyway, is my code right? Thank you.

Comment: @TungPham If you want to demo concurrency, you need to make threads that do things that are capable of being done concurrently. Writing to a single output stream will force serialization. Concurrency is impossible with your code. You can, however, get the output you want by yielding. But that's the opposite of concurrency, having each thread "hand off" to the next thread.

Comment: @@David Schwartz, If I run it several times, it somehow prints the same value of "a" which is not 20. It still shows the concurrency.
Also, If I use "Mutex" to avoid concurrency, only thread 0 runs through increment function until a=0, that's not what I want.

Comment: @TungPham What do you want? Do you want to force the output you say you want, even though that will mean there's no concurrency at all? If you want actual concurrency, you'll have to write code that doesn't involve lots of threads trying to do nothing but access the same resource.

Comment: No, I mean, when I use "Mutex" to avoid the concurrency, only threard 0 run though the function until a=0 instead of others. Assume there are 20 tickets and 6 people want to buy them. then the first one buys the whole 20 tickets.

Comment: @TungPham this is not a good example at all of concurrent execution: *at the same time*. Ex: splitting up two 10000x10000 matrices for multiplication into a work queue of "multiply this row by that column and put the result there" items. Each row/col multiply is independent of the others. The only shared resource that matters is the queue, which is locked only long enough to get the next item. to work on. This answer is correct. David has rightly pointed out this code is literally as concurrency-anti-friendly as you can get.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have to admit that, this is my homework and I have to show the uncontrolled and controlled concurrent access. For the uncontrolled one, I have done it by showing the same value. But for the second one, when I use "Mutex", only threard 0 run though the function until a=0 instead of others even I run it thousand times. so, I guess the starvation happens.